# Pandas DataFrame .attrs is not saved when saving dataframe with to_csv method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas df.attrs method to store metadata in dataframes. Unfortunately those are never saved when I use `to_arbitrary_type('filepath')` methods.
Can someone tell me the correct way to save dataframes such that the `df.attrs` get saved too?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is a reasonable way to include metadata inside a CSV file, which is basically just data separated by commas. Other df storage formats might work (most obviously just pickling the Python object, but look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/saving-metadata-with-dataframes-71f51f558d8e)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save/load pandas dataframe with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832397/save-load-pandas-dataframe-with-custom-attributes)

Comment: @Nick thanks, I saw this, I was hoping it had changed since then but extensive google had not revealed a more recent answer. I.e. I was hoping 4 years since then and more since .attrs was added to experimental, pandas would have added built-in functionality.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander thanks a lot this seems like another workaround, I'll try this too. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot save metadata of a dataframe in any file type. You can do so with HD5, as presented [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-metadata-to-a-dataframe-or-series-with-pandas-in-python/).

Comment: Oh thank you! :-( I saw some answers that said this but they were all several years old and I was hoping this had changed.